# How to solve the error_syntax error near '< '

Tags: sql, sql-server

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 3 Incorrect syntax near '<'.

I got the above error message every time I tried to execute the below query.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[FM1]
   SET [Datum] = <Datum, smalldatetime,>
      ,[Gesamtzeit] = <Gesamtzeit, nvarchar(5),>
```

Comment: hi, please provided version of you sql server; why you use <Datum, smalldatetime> ?

Comment: This seems like an auto-generated code from SSMS, make sure to always review the code you are going to execute before executing it.

Answer (score 2):

You can try this no need to specify datatype here.

```
UPDATE [dbo].[FM1]
   SET [Datum] = 'YourValue'
      ,[Gesamtzeit] = 'YourValue'
      where ...
```